# JAVA - POST API CALL

Tags: java, api, http, post

I'm trying to call an API with basic authorization but without success.

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();

HttpAuthenticationFeature feature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic("username", "password");
clientConfig.register( feature) ;

clientConfig.register(JacksonFeature.class);

Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient( clientConfig );
String URL = "http://localhost:8080/teste/" + taskId + "/start";
WebTarget webTarget = client.target(URL);

Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder =  webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
Response response = invocationBuilder.get();

System.out.println(response.getStatus());
System.out.println(response.getStatusInfo());

if(response.getStatus() == 200)
{
    System.out.println(response.getStatus());
}
```

I'm getting many errors like:

> Could not find a suitable constructor in org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.SourceProvider$SaxSourceReader class.
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Errors were discovered while reifying SystemDescriptor(

Can you help me please?
Some tips?

Greetings

Comment: Have you tested it with Postman? Just to double check that your backend works and it is not an issue with the code you just copied here.

Answer (score 0):

String URL = "http://localhost:8080/teste/" + taskId + "/enable";
HttpPut request = new HttpPut(URL);

```
    CredentialsProvider provider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    provider.setCredentials(
            AuthScope.ANY,
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user", "password")
    );

    try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(provider)
            .build()) {
        try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request)) {

            // 401 if wrong user/password
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity != null) {
                // return it as a String
                String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                System.out.println(result);
            }

        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I'm using this solution now and its work, but i need to send a raw body in this request, how i can do that?

Any tip?

Thanks

Comment: If you have another question, please ask a new question instead of posting it as answer